# Same community is rendering differently in different sandboxes

Tags: lightning, css, community-builder

I have a dev sandbox with a community where there is a flow component. I am using custom css to override some styling on the flow `Previous` button:

```
.flow-button__BACK button {
    background: #7c4199 !important; 
    color: white; 
}

.flow-button__BACK button:hover {
    color: white !important;
}
```

The element I am overriding looks like the below in Chrome dev console when inspected:

```
<lightning-button flowruntime-navigationbar_navigationbar="" class="slds-button flow-button__BACK">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" type="button">Previous</button>
</lightning-button>
```

When inspecting the exact same element in the community in a different sandbox (UAT) the element looks like this in Chrome dev console when inspected:

```
<button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral flow-button__BACK" data-aura-rendered-by="478:0">
    <!--render facet: 479:0-->Previous<!--render facet: 482:0-->
</button>
```

I am really confused as to why this is happening. There are no settings I can see in either sandbox which are different. I have checked the Digital Experience settings, page settings, administration workspace, flow versions are identical and theme settings are all identical.

Comment: Are the two orgs on different platform versions? We are in the Winter '23 upgrade window so different orgs can be on different versions.

Comment: They're on the same - I checked Enterprise API and both on API 56.0